# Can Google index and follow RouterLink links?

Tags: angular, seo

Assuming I have Angular 2 App, routing with RouterLink, Google can read it as a follow link and index it?

In other words: Can google bot recognize the routerlinks normally as links?

Comment: googlebot sees html. it doesn't see your code, it will not execute javascript. if something doesn't exist in the html, then googlebot doesn't see it/won't follow it, basically.

Comment: contents coming from js are not indexed, although there are ways to implement this. you can check what has been indexed by google by typing,
cache:http://yoururl.com

Comment: The idea that Googlebot can't render JavaScipt has been out of date for a while. This is probably worth a read: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

Answer (score 3):

This is the argument in Angular Universal:

> Optimized for Search Engines: Although Googlebot crawls and renders
>   most dynamic sites, many search engines expect plain HTML

**So for google not needed**

---

**but for other crawlers** you might need..  Angular Univeral

Answer (score 1):

According to Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/links-crawlable) **googlebot can't navigate through pages using routerLink**.

You can try and **add both attributes - href and routerLink**. In my tests the **interactivity for the user didn't change** and it still worked like a single page application. I think **googlebot should be able to follow the link thanks to href** attribute and ignore routerLink, but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot, but you should take a look at [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/). With it, you can pre-render your app on the server side and Google is able to understand it.